# Dell Inspiron i5565 Laptop without USB-C port can I use a USB-C dock with an adapter?

Tags: usb-c

This laptop does not have a USB-C port, but If I use a a USB-3 to USB-C adapter such as this one
https://www.nonda.co/products/usb-c-to-usb-3-0-mini-adapter
Should I be able to connect to a USB-C type hub such as this one?
[link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07FX2LW35)
The goal, would be to simply plug into the dock and get access to a full sized keyboard, wired ethernet connection and external monitor via hdmi

Comment: There are similar hubs for standard USB ports.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I just remembered I already have one.  Will need to check its ports, but I think its an old one.

Comment: JUst to add some background: The USB type C plug is a standard for a plug. It does not nessecary have USB communaction over it. It really is merely aplug format. One which is often used by USB 3 (5Gb/s), USB 3 (10Gb/sec), USB2 (YEs, even on a new plug this is perfectly valid), thunderbolt-3 (which supports TB3 PCIe communcation and often can multiplex DP video. And which often is connected in a way that if you plug in an USB device instewad of a TB3 device that the connection are reroutes to an USB chip). So plenty room for confusion here.

Comment: A classic USB hub might be a safer bet. That will almost certainly work, be cheaper and grant you a few connections for mouse, keyboard, USB Ethernet dongle.... But no decent speed high res video). Though I am using just that for a second low res screen (1920x1200) with only excel sheets and no movies and no gaming.

Comment: Yes, hence the question - putting a USB-3 adapter onto the male end of the USB-C docking plug.  Will using this with a powered Dock such as the Dell D6000 https://www.dell.com/en-us/member/shop/dell-universal-dock-d6000/apd/452-bcyt/pc-accessories

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory yes, but in practice...
(Disclaimer: I'm an IT guy and I need to support 100's of customers with various models of laptops and docks. I hate these docks.)

There is a chance you will face all sorts of compatibility issues.
The USB-C standard allows for a large range of optional features and because every manufacturer can combine those in different ways USB-C isn't as standard/generic as the docking station and laptop vendors would like you to believe.
(E.g there are at least 3 different ways to send video over USB-C. Only 1 of those works with a USB 3 converter. And the other 2 only work if the dock and the laptop both use the same system.)

Because of that these docks are quite notorious for having issues even if connected directly to USB-C.
Adding an additional USB-C/USB 3 converter in the mix can only make matters worse.

But such docks also exist with a regular USB 3.0 connection (as Gabriel Garcia also mentioned in the comments). These are far less prone to issues.

Be advised that regardless of USB-C or USB 3.0 if the video-output on such a dock is delivered by a USB-connected graphics chip it will have FAR LESS performance than a real video-card.
At Full-HD resolutions most USB docks will struggle to give you a 30 Hz display. Video especially can be choppy. And gaming on a screen connected like that is out of the question.
Additionally: On USB 3 the video-card and the ethernet interface will compete for bandwidth on the USB bus which is also not a good thing.
Personally I can't work on a display connected to such a dock for more than a few minutes without getting a headache due to the lousy image-quality.